# Validate semi colon separated e-mail with Zod resolver and react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I need to validate semi colon separated e-mails but the below validation does not work and I cannot use .regex. I believe .refine should be able to do this but I can't find a good way to do it.

```
const customSchema = z.object({
factoryEmail: z.
  .string()
  .email()
});
```

I've tried the following

```
const customSchema = z.object({
factoryEmail: z.
  .string()
  .email()
  .refine((emailValue) => emailValue.split(';').map(function(item) {
   customSchema.parse(item)
});
```

The above does not work. What would I need to do in .refine to be able to validate semicolon separated e-mails, for example

playerone@gmail.com, playertwo@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const customSchema = z.object({
  factoryEmail: z
    .string()
    .refine((emailValue) => emailValue.split(";").every((item) => z.string().email().safeParse(item).success)),
});
```

This validates that the string is emails, separated by a semicolon `;`.

```js
const a = customSchema.safeParse({
  factoryEmail: "foo@example.com",
}).success;

const b = customSchema.safeParse({
  factoryEmail: "foo@example.com;banana@example.com",
}).success;

const c = customSchema.safeParse({
  factoryEmail: "foo@example.com,banana@example.com",
}).success;

console.log(a, b, c);
```

This outputs `true true false`.